# Rails Routing - :resource_id vs :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my routes.rb:

```
resources :posts do
    get "test"
end
```

This produces the usual RESTful routes with `/post/:id/...`. However, I also get `/post/:post_id/test`.

Now my problem is that sometimes the parameter is named :id and sometimes it is :post_id. How can I make it uniform?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify :on => :member, otherwise it is acting as a nested resource.

```
resources :posts do
    get 'test', :on => :member
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was a nested resource by default. I thought :on => :member was the default already :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't make it uniform.  It's `:id` when it's the target resource and `:post_id` when it is the parent of some other target resource (i.e. nested resources).  This is a Rails convention.